# Write a function to find all data from Mongo DB and pass to controller

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I am new in Mean Stack. I install the express in MVC model. 
I have a model named Data

```
let getAllData = ()=>{
    Data.find({},(err,data)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        var datas = {};

        data.forEach((data)=>{
            datas[data._id]=data;
        });

        console.log(datas);
    });
}



module.exports = {
    Data,
    store,
    getAllData
}
```

I want to call getAllData from a controller

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passport = require("passport");
var User = require("../models/User");
var DataModel = require("../models/Data");

var userController = {};



// Access to root page
userController.home = function(req, res) {
  // res.render('index');
  // res.send(Data.find);
    DataModel.getAllData();
    res.render('index',{//I want to send all the data to this view and view them from the page});
  }
```

All I want is to make a function in the model to access all the data and show them in my view with a controller in middle. I am totally new and I could not exactly find the solution anywhere.

Thank you.

Comment: Heads up, of it is a lot of data you'll want to get it in batches.

Answer (score 0):

You should use async await for this. This will allow you to call the function, wait for the promise to resolve and then respond the to request.

```
const getAllData = async () => {
  return Data.find({})
    .then(data => {})
    .catch(error => {
      throw error;
    });
};

module.exports = {
  Data,
  store,
  getAllData
};
```

When you define your function as async it will return a promise, so you can await its response.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passport = require("passport");
var User = require("../models/User");
var DataModel = require("../models/Data");

var userController = {};

// Access to root page
userController.home = async function(req, res) {
  // res.render('index');
  // res.send(Data.find);
  const data = await DataModel.getAllData();
  res.render("index", data);
};
```

Comment: Don't mix `async-await` with `Promise` syntax, use one or the other. The `getAllData` function can simply return the `Promise` returned by `Data.find`

Comment: Why? What's the problem with it? Where would you catch errors?

Comment: It's like mixing `.map()` and `for` loops in same function. And for the answer you posted, you just throw the error anyways. Error handling in Express should be delegated to error middleware anyways: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html